# `at` command: what is the meaning of the option `-w`?

Tags: command-line, at-command

I have a script that uses `at` command. And sometimes I receiving emails as this one:

```
Date: Mon,  3 Jul 2017 14:18:00 +0300 (EEST)
From: root <root@localhost.org>
To: root@localhost.org
Subject: Output from your job      173

Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Perhaps you want to use the -w option?
```

Of course I would use this option to prevent messages like this, but first I want to know what is the meaning of this option. Unfortunately `-w` option is not listed in [`man at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/at.1posix.html).

Does anyone know what exactly this option means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message is from your job, not from `at` (and `at` also does not have a `-w` option BTW). By default, `at` sends STDOUT and STDERR from any job via mail, unless specified otherwise.

---

Presumably, your job was a `iptables` task -- based on the message regarding `xtables`. And the `-w` (`--wait`) option of `iptables` waits for the `xtables` lock to be released, as suggested in the message.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, Heemayl! Apparently I must think more before asking. :)

Comment: @pa4080 It happens, no problem :)

Answer (score 4):

The error seems to be related to `iptables` command

[man iptables](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)

> **-w, --wait**
>       Wait for the xtables lock. To prevent multiple instances of the program from running concurrently, an attempt will be made to obtain
>   an exclusive lock at launch. By default, the program will exit if the
>   lock cannot be obtained. This option will make the program wait until
>   the exclusive lock can be obtained.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, Yaron! But Heemayl's answer appears first (we talk about 6 seconds) and I've accepted it.

Comment: @pa4080 - happy to help  :-)

Comment: @pa4080 :As general rule, it is worth waiting a little while before accepting an answer, in case a better one comes along (admittedly, that seems unlikely here where the solution is obvious once it is pointed out).  There is nothing to stop you *then* accepting the first one (but you might also want to consider accepting the best written one).